Visual Studio WinForms Editor won't save changes to a custom collection
I am trying to edit a collection property for a custom UserControl using the Collection Editor, but it doesn't save the changes I make. The collection is a custom class that subclasses List. The Collection Editor lets me add the values I want, doesn't give any errors, and even updates the control in the designer to how the control should look with the new values in the list. However, it doesn't create a resource for the modified list and doesn't generate code in the Designer file to deserialize the list and set the property to the saved list. My custom list class has the Serializable attribute, and I have also tried adding the Editor(typeof(CollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor)) attribute to the property, and it still doesn't save. I have tried with a normal List property, and I am able to get it to save.
Here's exactly what I'm talking about. Here is the collection editor, and I am able to add the following values:

I click "Ok". In the designer, doing this correctly updates the associated UserControl to look like the following, which is correct:

However, when I build and run the program, the UserControl looks like how it is when a list is not provided:

If I look at the designer after this, it updates back to the above default after a few seconds.
The problem is that it's not saving the resource for the modified list:

It also doesn't generate code similar to notifierListLabel1.Ints = (DataClasses.NotifierList<int>)resources.GetObject("notifierListLabel1.Ints") in the designer file.
What am I missing? Are there any attributes that I'm missing? I haven't been able to find anything online about this.
Edit: I've uploaded the relevant code here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e4t2Z4mKaCp3uxIwazRUSKrXEacOvymM/view?usp=sharing
Edit again: Here is the code that I think has the problem:
using SaveableCounters.DataClasses;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SaveableCounters.UserControls
{
    [DefaultEvent(nameof(OnTextChanged))]
    public partial class Counter2 : UserControl
    {
        [Browsable(true)]
        public int Count
        {
            get => int.Parse(counterField.Text);
            set => counterField.Text = value.ToString();
        }
        public string CountAsText => counterField.Text;

        private NotifierList<int> stepSizes;
        [Browsable(true)]
        // [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)] this makes it work but it shouldn't need to have this
        public NotifierList<int> StepSizes
        {
            get => stepSizes;
            set
            {
                stepSizes = value;
                if (stepSizes is null)
                    return;

                stepSizes.CollectionChanged += CreateButtonsForStepSizes;
                CreateButtonsForStepSizesActual();
            }
        }

        private List<Button> currentCounterButtons = new List<Button>();

        private const int buttonDefaultWidthAndHeight = 39;
        private int buttonBaseWidth;
        private int counterFieldBaseWidth;

        public Counter2(int startingCount, IEnumerable<int> stepSizes)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Count = startingCount;
            buttonBaseWidth = buttonDefaultWidthAndHeight - TextRenderer.MeasureText("+", counterField.Font).Width;
            counterFieldBaseWidth = buttonDefaultWidthAndHeight - TextRenderer.MeasureText(startingCount.ToString(), counterField.Font).Width;
            counterField.Width = buttonDefaultWidthAndHeight;

            counterField.TextChanged += ResizeCounterField;
            StepSizes = new NotifierList<int>(stepSizes);
        }

        public Counter2(int startingCount) : this(startingCount, new int[] { 1 })
        {
        }

        public Counter2() : this(0)
        {
        }

        [Browsable(true)]
        public new event EventHandler? OnTextChanged
        {
            add => counterField.TextChanged += value;
            remove => counterField.TextChanged -= value;
        }

        [Browsable(true)]
        public new event CancelEventHandler? Validating
        {
            add => counterField.Validating += value;
            remove => counterField.Validating -= value;
        }

        [Browsable(true)]
        public new event EventHandler? Validated
        {
            add => counterField.Validated += value;
            remove => counterField.Validated -= value;
        }

        protected virtual void CreateButtonsForStepSizes(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CreateButtonsForStepSizesActual();
        }

        private void CreateButtonsForStepSizesActual()
        {
            contents.SuspendLayout();
            SuspendLayout();

            foreach (Button button in currentCounterButtons)
            {
                contents.Controls.Remove(button);
            }
            currentCounterButtons.Clear();

            foreach (int stepSize in StepSizes)
            {
                Button countDownButton = new Button();
                Button countUpButton = new Button();

                if (stepSize == 1)
                {
                    countDownButton.Text = "-";
                    countUpButton.Text = "+";
                }
                else
                {
                    countDownButton.Text = $"-{stepSize}";
                    countUpButton.Text = $"+{stepSize}";
                }

                int textWidth = Math.Max(
                    TextRenderer.MeasureText(countDownButton.Text, countDownButton.Font).Width,
                    TextRenderer.MeasureText(countUpButton.Text, countUpButton.Font).Width
                );

                Console.WriteLine($"{buttonBaseWidth} {textWidth}");
                Size buttonSize = new Size(buttonBaseWidth + textWidth, buttonDefaultWidthAndHeight);
                countDownButton.Size = buttonSize;
                countUpButton.Size = buttonSize;

                countDownButton.Margin = Padding.Empty;
                countUpButton.Margin = Padding.Empty;

                countDownButton.Click += (_, _) => Count -= stepSize;
                countUpButton.Click += (_, _) => Count += stepSize;

                contents.Controls.Add(countDownButton);
                contents.Controls.SetChildIndex(countDownButton, 0);
                contents.Controls.Add(countUpButton);

                currentCounterButtons.Add(countDownButton);
                currentCounterButtons.Add(countUpButton);
            }

            ResumeLayout();
            contents.ResumeLayout();
        }

        private void ResizeCounterField(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int newWidth = counterFieldBaseWidth + TextRenderer.MeasureText(counterField.Text, counterField.Font).Width;
            counterField.Width = newWidth;
        }

        private void counterField_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!int.TryParse(CountAsText, out _))
                e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}

I was trying to make a minimal example, but the collection actually saved for it. I thought this meant I just needed to delete and remake the form with the problem, but that didn't fix it, so I'm providing the real code. The code has the custom list (NotifierList), the UserControl (Counter2), and the Form (SaveableCountersForm). I can't use ObservableCollection because it gives me an error when it tries to serialize it about being unable to load a type "System.Collections.ObjectModel.SimpleMonitor"
which I couldn't find any information about online.

SHOW. US. THE. CODE. By the way, if you want to define a custome collection then you should be inheriting Collection<T>, not List<T>. The latter can be inherited but is not intended for the purpose like the former is.

@jmcilhinney Sorry. I've now provided the code.

Please don't let us guess and post the relevant code here. Do you have the collection property decorated with the [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)] attribute?

@dr.null I didn't have that attribute. I've added it, and now it works! However, the minimal example I talked about didn't have that attribute, and yet it worked. I think it might be something with the Counter2 class. I will post the code for the class on the post so we can find out why it needs that attribute to work.

Good, then problem solved. Yes, you need this attribute to add designer support and serialize the collection in the x.designer.cs (or in place if you don't have one) file. Notes: Move  stepSizes.CollectionChanged += CreateButtonsForStepSizes; to the ctor. Initialize the object and attach the handler. Let the Count property getter returns a backing field (say _count) of type int and int.TryParse(counterField.Text, out _count); the new values in the setter. Do not do this contents.Controls.Remove(button); loop the collection backward and dispose (button.Dispose();) them....
